# What would happen to Earth if Jupiter's orbit were twice as close to Earth?

Tags: science-based

Earth is about 150 million kilometers from the sun. Jupiter is about 780 million km from the sun. So if Jupiter suddenly were to be only ((780-150)/2) 315 million km from the sun, but its orbit were to remain stable at that distance (assuming that the orbit can stay stable), what would happen?

If the orbit can't stay stable, would Jupiter fall into the sun? How long might that take? Would Jupiter draw Mars or even Earth into its orbit?

*To limit the scope of this question, I'm purely asking about the physical effects and if the Earth or other planets would be destroyed or have their climates significantly altered.*

Comment: Did you sweep up the asteroid belt and Mars to make room?

Comment: VTC: This is a [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/40609). The list of answers is metaphorically infinitely long. You have not expressed any limits, conditions, or restrictions (required by the [help/on-topic]) or established criteria for selecting a best answer. The [help/dont-ask] states, "To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question."

Comment: Be aware also that the question in the title is slightly different from that in the body, which rankles a bit. Can you narrow the focus perhaps to ensure there is a best answer as JBH indicates.

Answer (score 2):

**No change**

Even halving the distance, Jupiter has a negligible influence when compared to the moon.

Moon mass: $m_m = 7 \times 10^{22}$ kg

Moon distance: $r_m = $ 0.38 million km

Jupiter mass: $m_J = 2 \times 10^{27}$ kg

Jupiter distance $r_J = $ 600 million km.

Note the units don't matter when we compute the ratio. The ratio of gravitational forces is

$$\frac{m_n}{m_j}\frac{r_J^2}{r_n^2} =\frac{7 \times 10^{23}}{2 \times 10^{27}} \frac{600^2}{0.38^2} = \frac{3.5}{10000}\left(\frac{600}{0.38} \right)^2 \simeq \frac{3.5}{10000}1600^2=\frac{3.5}{10000}2560000 =  3.5 \times 256  \simeq 900.$$

So the moon influences gravity 900 times more than Jupiter. Make Jupiter twice as close and you make it four times as strong. So 900/4 = 225 weaker than the moon.

Comment: That might be true for a two body system. The solar system is a multi body system and intrinsically chaotic.